# Problemas con mi CSS al agregar Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap, sass

estoy intentando colocar un carousel de boots pero afecta a mi CSS.

Asi se ve el proyecto sin Bootstrap:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi se ve una vez agregado Boots con jsDelivr (tanto el CSS como JS):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien afecta el nav en version mobile:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con !important en mi css, pero no se arregla del todo y hasta en un momento dejo de funcionar el JS.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a [es.so] te invito a leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour] tu pregunta carece de información para detectar tu problema, por favor crea un [example] o puede que tu pregunta termine cerrada.